# wp_mail attachment woes!

Tags: wp-mail

Evening all,

Been banging my head for hours, tried a dozen posts about this but still can't get my image to arrive my email!!

My form contains this...

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

My php looks like this...

```
function sendContactFormToSiteAdminPosition() {

try {
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['yourself']) || empty($_POST['contribute']) || empty($_POST['question'])) {
      throw new Exception('Bad form parameters. Check the markup to make sure you are naming the inputs correctly.');
    }
    if (!is_email($_POST['email'])) {
      throw new Exception('Email address not formatted correctly.');
    }

    $subject = 'Website enquiry';
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= array('From: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$_POST['email'].'>');
    $send_to = "kevin@myaddress.co.uk";
    $message = "bla bla";

 //$mail_attachment =  array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/aa_surfer.png'); // this works btw 

    if ($_FILES) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
                $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
                if ( $movefile['file'] ) {
                    //echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                    var_dump( $movefile['file']);
                } else {
                    //echo "NOT WORKING!!";
                    var_dump( $movefile['file']);
                }
    }

    $attachments = $movefile['file'];

 if (wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments)) {
      echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Contact message sent.'));
      exit;
    } else {
      throw new Exception('Failed to send email. Check AJAX handler.');
    }


  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
    exit;
  }
}
add_action("wp_ajax_position_send", "sendContactFormToSiteAdminPosition");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_position_send", "sendContactFormToSiteAdminPosition");
```

If someone could please show me the error of my ways, before my monitor is launched across the room. The email sends fine, but no attachment. When I type in a direct path to an image on the server, it works perfectly.

I don't really get any part of that `wp_handle_part`, so I imagine that's the culprit.

I can provide files if it helps.

Thanks!

Comment: still trying to get this working, any help appreciated.

Comment: What is output from your `var_dump()`?  Have you checked your webserver and confirmed that the file is actually being uploaded successfully?